# Unity2D how do i calculate jump height using Velocity & Gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i would like to calculate the jump height. but i don't know how

Example:

```
RightBody2D rb = this.GetComponent<RightBody2D>();

// Do jump
rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump);

// Here is the question. how do i calculate jump height
float jumpHeight = CalculateJumpHeight(jump); 

indicator.transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, jumpHeight);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We invite you to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. It is hard for anyone to help you, because your question is not clear, it lacks debugging context and a [mcve].

Comment: You can calculate this by the drag of your rigidbody. If the drag of the rigidbody is one unit each frame, and the velocity is 10, you could do this: 10 + (10 - 1) + (10 - 2) + ... + (10 - 9) + (10 -10). This was not tested, and I think that velocity does not use meters.

Comment: Gravity is probably different than drag, but I am not sure.

Comment: Are you setting the rb.velocity just once or do you update the velocity over a number of frames?

Comment: i'm setting rb.velocity just once. NOTE this is not my real code but this code is just to understand what i would. and i'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate this as follows, however, it's not going to be perfectly accurate in every instance because Unity's physics system isn't deterministic.

```
    float timeToReachApexOfJump = Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y / Physics.gravity.y);
    float heightOfJump = (0.5f * Physics.gravity.y * timeToReachApexOfJump) + (rb.velocity.y * timeToReachApexOfJump);
    Debug.Log(timeToReachApexOfJump);
    Debug.Log(heightOfJump);
```

Comment: Thanks that's what i need :}